# should i make a data.js file in which i'll put the json data or any other method to proceed with this use case?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, frontend

building a Search result page hosting a json in a static npm http-server (a dummy) and build a search result page in react+redux (you ay use any other state management other than redux as well)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i need to make a search result page hosting json data on a dummy server using react+redux !! How should i put json data in it by making data.js file or any other method?